# Facebook API - App request - invites friends filter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have found several friends filter option while invites friends from facebook App.

What will be logic behind **"LIKES GAMES"** that I saw at the sim social

also  found some more on  Zynga invites :

1. **Recommended friends**
2. **My Active Zynga Friend**

Not able to find any logic behind this. I build a custom friends invite plugin by using graph and FB.ui api. Here my client want to give some filter like I mentioned above.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: The Request dialog has the option in itself as 'filters'. you can specify the filters in any of the following all, app_users ,or app_non_users. All will all users, app_users will display only the application users and app_non_users will display the users who are not using the application. You can have more than value for the filter as comma separated value. This will automatically create the dropdown in the dialog. If you are using the graph API, u can specify the same property.

Comment: Thanks @Vijay for the quick reply

The problem with  Request dialog is that we cannot customize the look of UI. FBML one is possible to do that. Due to FB depreciating FBML, myself creating a customized UI by using graph API and FB.UI, here I have filter like APP_USER and NON_APP_USER. not able to do more than this.

Do you know the logic behind  "LIKES GAMES" filter in The Sim Social game [link](http://apps.facebook.com/thesimssocial/)

Comment: What values are they passing when initialising the dialog? You could try using the same parameters and see if you get the same list

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, making a filter for the invite dialog like the one from The Sim Social game is done this way:

1. First make your app require access their likes and friend likes by asking for the permissions user_likes and friends_likes
2. Make calls to the graph api like this one for every friend https://graph.facebook.com/_friends_ids_/likes?access_token=_valid_acess_token_
   This will give you info like:

   ```
   "data": [
     {
        "name": "Swing Facil, en espa\u00f1ol",
        "category": "Website",
        "id": "277416935626207",
        "created_time": "2011-10-21T11:14:06+0000"
     },
     {
        "name": "Frontier Ville Friend Finder",
        "category": "Games/toys",
        "id": "127903637247191",
        "created_time": "2010-11-03T21:31:06+0000"
     }
      ]
   }
   ```
3. This way you can get all the friends likes info, now you just have to look for the 'like' name or category you want to make the filter for and keep those friend id's in an array

The filter param for the request dialog will be something like

```
[{name: 'Filter name', user_ids: [1, 2, 3]}, {name: 'Other filter name', user_ids: [4,5,6]}]
```

To enable the user to select who they wish to send a request to, you can invoke the Request Dialog as below.

```
function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request',
    filters: [{name: 'Filter name', user_ids: [1, 2, 3]}, {name: 'Other filter name', user_ids: [4,5,6]}],
  });
}
```

For more info, i recommend you to read [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

I hope this help you.