# How to filter a facebook friend list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the graph api and would like to get a list of my friends who play games at facebook. Is this possible?

Comment: but on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/ they write "Friends that play games

Another interesting filter would be to highlight users that are highly engaged with your game and are friends of the current user. Providing suggested recipients like this for Requests can result in a higher rate of conversion for accepting the Request. As a result the sending user is more likely to have their request accepted and continue to be engaged in your app." Sounds to me as if there would be a way....

Comment: What about graph.facebook.com/user_id/games? Wouldn't that be a way? I tried it but everything is empty...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API - App request - invites friends filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875312/facebook-api-app-request-invites-friends-filter)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, the only application/game connection you be able to discover is with your own application/game (or other applications you own, based on your own data)

Some notes to you statements in comments:

*"Friends who play games"* section of Request Dialog describing way to filter only friends who is using **your** application:

> Another interesting filter would be to highlight users that are highly **engaged with your game** and are friends of the current user.

`games` connection of `user` is not really list of games user play but just data based on user's likes:

> Games the user has added to the Arts and Entertainment section of their profile.